# Integer index behavior in neo4j + lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j

I want to index an integer field on nodes in a large database (~20 million nodes). The behavior I would expect to work is as follows:

```java
HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// Add node to graph (inserter is an instance of BatchInserter)
properties.put("id", 1000);
long node = inserter.createNode(properties);

// Add index 
index.add(node, properties);

// Retrieve node by index. RETURNS NULL!
IndexHits<Node> hits = index.query("id", 1000);
```

I add the key-value pair to the index and then query by it. Sadly, this doesn't work.

My current hackish workaround is to use a Lucene object and query by range:

```java
// Add index 
properties.put("id", ValueContext.numeric(1000).indexNumeric());
index.add(node, properties);

// Retrieve node by index. This still returns null
IndexHits<Node> hits = index.query("id", 1000);

// However, this version works
hits = index.query(QueryContext.numericRange("id", 1000, 1000, true, true));
```

This is perfectly functional, but the range query is really dumb. Is there a way to run exact integer queries without this `QueryContext.numericRange` mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index lookup you require is an exact match, not a query.

Try replacing 
    `index.query("id", 1000)`
with 
    `index.get("id", 1000)`

Comment: This works if you do away with the `ValueContext` object. You lose the ability to query by range, but that is irrelevant in my case.

Thanks!